# Observable fromArray

Tags: angular, observable

I currently have a problem with Angular2 and Observable object.

I have a Component who calls a Service : a real one linked to an api and a fake one.

The service linked to the API works well but when I use the fake one, I want to return an Array from Observable object but I have this error :"Observable_1.Observable.fromArray is not a function"

Here is my code :

Component :

```
this._raceService.list().subscribe(newRaces => { 

  this.races = newRaces;
});
```

Real Service :

```
list(){ return this._http.get('http://dev.backend.com/api.php', options).map(res => res.json()); }
```

Fake service :

```
list() { return Observable.fromArray([{ name: 'London' }]); }
```

Can you help me plz ?

Cheers

Answer (score 29):

should that be...

```
Rx.Observable.from(yourarray)
```

fromArray seems to be deprecated

Comment: Thanks but when I use Observable.from I have this at compilation :
error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

And how to use Rx.Observable when Rx has no exported member ?

Comment: is that a typescript error relating to the list method signature? do you need maybe list(): any {...

Comment: Don't get it what list() supposed to do ? List isn't either an Observable property.. 

I need a method from an Observable object which takes an array in parameter.. and finally has to be "subscribeable" as my Component calls subscribe on the result.

Comment: I have a similar issue but in my case, no errors, but it is not triggering an event downstream when i .map(..) on it

Comment: This is more appropriate answer IMO

Answer (score 17):

Answer needs to be updated for RxJS 6, it is now

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';

const observable = from([ { a: 1, b: 2 } ]);
```

Comment: Work with rxjs version 6. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

`Observable.fromArray()` was removed in RxJS version 5, use `from()`

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
...
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and had to add this import statement in my component:

`import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromArray';`

I found the import to add by searching for `fromArray` in the `Rx.js` file I was referencing (be careful since there may be different versions of the file in your project):

```
System.register("rxjs/add/observable/fromArray", ["rxjs/Observable", "rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable"], true, function(require, exports, module) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, after some research in my code ...

I imported:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Instead of:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

Hope it can help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case this form worked out good:
`import { Observable } from "rxjs";`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I believe you may be getting this because fromArray has been deprecated.

import rxjs/Observable to prevent importing other parts of rxjs you don't need

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

fromArray has been deprecated. Instead use

```
list() { return Observable.from([{ name: 'London' }]); }
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation to your post that talks about how the code works. This allows new developers to understand what the code does.

Comment: @CalebKleveter - thanks for pointing this out. I had comments for the answer, but they were not obvious to the reader as they were code comments in side the block of code. I've updated the answer to pull the comments out.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

const promiseSource = from(new Promise(resolve => resolve('Hello World!')));
```

https://learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html