# Rx.Observable.from is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, rxjs

I started learning reactive programming in javascript using RxJS and it's my first time using node. I don't exactly know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
const array = [
    '1', 'Max', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'IoT', '6', '7', '8', '9'
];

const stream = Rx.Observable.from(array);
```

**This is the error:**

`TypeError: Rx.Observable.from is not a function`

**This is what I've tried so far:**

I've installed RxJS using `node install rxjs`, nothing else.
I've tried importing `from` directly using `import`:

`import { from } from 'rxjs';`

When I've tried importing `from` using `import`, I've gotten this error:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

I've tried to go in the `package-lock.json` file and add the type of the module to `module`, but I've gotten the same error:

This is what I've tried doing to the `package-lock.json` file:

```json
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": {
      "version": "7.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-7.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7SQDi7xeTMCJpqViXh8gL/lebcwlp3d831F05+9B44A4B0WfsEwUQHR64gsH1kvJ+Ep/J9K2+n1hVl1CsGN23w==",
      "requires": {
        "tslib": "~2.1.0"
      },
      "type": "module"
    },
    "tslib": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-2.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hcVC3wYEziELGGmEEXue7D75zbwIIVUMWAVbHItGPx0ziyXxrOMQx4rQEVEV45Ut/1IotuEvwqPopzIOkDMf0A==",
      "type": "module"
    }
  }
}
```

Sources:

[Cannot use import statement outside a module...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

[`fromArray` is deprecated, use `from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890906/observable-fromarray)

The question is :

**How can I use `from` in RxJS**

Answer (score 0):

Your import syntax seems correct, One shouldn't temper `XXXX.lock.json` file as its strictly for package management purpose.
May be this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-heisenberg-11soj?file=/src/index.ts) link could help you understand issue in your setup.